# DOMNode::getNodePath: does it take into account namespace?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a weird behaviour here.

I have a snippet of code that I used to ran under zend framework 2 php (don't remember what version of it) and everything works like a charm.

For some reasons I'd changed this and run it under local PHP (5.3.25) as I started a new project over Symfony2, but I've took some snippet of code that could be useful for me.

However, now this code ins't working anymore:

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns',"http://somenamespace.org/FOLDER/2013"); //casual ns used for this example
$foo = $xpath->query('//ns:AvailStatusMessage');
//some elaboration here
$barXPathString = $foo->getElementsByTagName('bar')->item(0)->getNodePath();
$foobar = $xpath->query($barXPathString .'/*[@fooBarAttribute="Available"]');
//some elaboration here
```

Result is that `$foobar` is null (with previous version it wasn't). Obviously my code isn't changed. Although XML is important, this question ins't about "query correctness" (I know that is correct, because it worked into previous version) but about the following:

If I do: `$this->logger->debug('X PATH STRING: '.$barXPathString);` result is

```
/OTA_HotelAvailGetRS/AvailStatusMessages/AvailStatusMessage/bar
```

but there isn't namespace. So i was wondering if between PHP version, this implementation is changed (don't know if this is issue maker, but I'm running crazy)

Is anyone aware of this?

Comment: It is not clear from your question why you're executing `DOMXPath::query()` twice. From the example you give, there is no need for that and you can do it with a single XPath query. Please elaborate, you might be looking in the wrong place for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of how `getNodePath()` works, trying to build up the XPath by manually cobbling it together looks like the wrong approach here. `DOMXPath::query` accepts a context node argument, and you should use that:

```
$firstBar = $foo->getElementsByTagName('bar')->item(0);
$foobar = $xpath->query('*[@fooBarAttribute="Available"]', $firstBar);
```

Also as hakre points out, your code is a bit confusing. `DOMNodeList` doesn't have a `getElementsByTagName()` method, so I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here:

```
$barXPathString = $foo->getElementsByTagName('bar')->item(0)->getNodePath();
```

Wouldn't it just be:

```
$barXPathString = $foo->item(0)->getNodePath();
```

Comment: You're right, I'd re-elaborated my question and committed some errors but your approach is the right one to me